# Average of divisors of n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, divisor-sum

Let n be a natural number and let $f(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{d(n)}$ be the arithmetical average of n's divisors. Either prove or give a counterexample that for all natural numbers like n, **which are not prime**, $f(n)\leq\frac{3n}{8}+1$ and show when does the equality hold.

Comment: What are "natural numbers like $n$"?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. It would be good to read the advice on [how to ask a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit it to explain what progress you have made and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider including the divisors of $n$ in this average in pairs whose product is $n$, starting with the "extremal" pair $(1,n)$ and continuing by reducing the larger divisor and increasing the smaller divisor in each step. (If $n$ is a square, the unpaired divisor $\sqrt n$ also needs to be considered.)

The average of a pair $(d,n/d)$ is $(d+n/d)/2$, and this is maximal for $d=1$ and minimal for $d=\sqrt n$. Thus if $n$ is not prime, we can bound the average from above by the average of the first two pairs, and we can bound the contribution of the second pair from above by using $d=2$:

\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma(n)}{d(n)}
&\le
\frac{1+n+2+n/2}4
\\
&=
\frac38n+\frac34
\\
&\lt
\frac38n+1\;.
\end{align}

In the special case where $n$ is the square of a prime, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma(n)}{d(n)}
&=
\frac{1+n+\sqrt n}3
\\
&=\frac38n+1-\frac{n-8\sqrt n+16}{24}
\\
&=\frac38n+1-\frac{(\sqrt n-4)^2}{24}
\\
&\le
\frac38n+1
\;,
\end{align}

with equality holding only for $n=16$, which isn't the square of a prime. Thus the inequality in fact holds for all composite $n$, not just for $n\gt10$, and equality never holds.

Comment: Thanks, but why did you use d=2? How about the case n was not divisible by 2 at all? And also, how do you know if the average of those  2 pairs (1,n,n/2,2) is lesser than the whole average?

Comment: @CODE: On the first question: I made no assumption about $n$ being divisible by $2$. I merely used the given hypothesis that $n$ is not prime, which implies that it has some divisor other than $1$ and $n$. Either there is only one such divisor, namely if $n$ is the square of a prime, which is the second case I treated; or there is at least one pair $(d,n/d)$ of such divisors other than the pair $(1,n)$. The average $(d+n/d)/2$ of this pair is less than or equal to the corresponding average for $d=2$. On the second question: it isn't; in fact I made use of the fact that it's greater.

Comment: So, still about the second question, how did you prove it for the average of all of pairs only with proving for the first two pairs?

Comment: @CODE: I'm not sure what more to say about this. The average of each of the first two pairs is higher than the average of any of the remaining pairs; this is because $(d+n/d)/2$ decreases from $d=1$ to $d=\sqrt n$. Thus, including more of the remaining pairs could only lower the average. If that isn't clear, perhaps you could point out more specifically which part of the argument isn't clear to you?

Comment: Ohh, thanks now. I understood.