# Show that $6$ is the only balanced number (one whose average size of divisor is equal to $n/2$).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My mind is blank. I don't even know where to start.

We want to find a balanced number whose average size of divisor is half of the number itself, i.e. $$\sigma(n)/d(n)=n/2$$

I guess we can find out what the LHS looks like by substituting the formulas for $\sigma (n)$ and $d(n)$. I get a fairly complicated formula which I don't really know how to simplify.

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383167/average-of-divisors-of-n) quickly gets you to a simple finite search.

Comment: You should try a few examples, say, $N<10^5$, and report results here.

Comment: @markvs Well $n/2$ goes up in a steady linear fashion, by increments of $0.5$, whereas $\sigma(n)/d(n)$, at least what I have computed from $1$ to $10$ goes up and down and up. These values are very close to $n/2$ but doesn't quite hit the mark except for when $n=6$; overshoots for values $0<n<6$ and $n=7$ and undershoots for $7<n<x$ with $x$ unknown because I haven't computed that far! I don't see a pattern so far!

Comment: When $n\gg10$, you may see a pattern.  Surely $n$ cannot be a prime. A square? A product of two primes? In any case you should convince the audience here that you have done some work. Counting to 10 is not work,

Comment: @markvs okay fine. But you made a good point that $n$ cannot be prime. I guess I can try to work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383167/average-of-divisors-of-n) may provide a shortcut as pointed out by lulu in the comments. This is my long mechanical solution.

Let $\prod_i{p_i^{k_i}}$ be the prime factorization of $n > 1$. We then have
$$\sigma(n) = \prod_i{\frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i - 1}}$$
and
$$d(n) = \prod_i{k_i + 1}$$
All this lets rewrite $\sigma(n)/d(n) = n/2$ as
$$\prod_i{\frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{(p_i - 1)(k_i + 1)}} = \frac{1}{2}\prod_i{p_i^{k_i}}$$
from which we get
$$\prod_i{\frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i^{k_i + 1} - p_i^{k_i}}} = \frac{1}{2}\prod_i{k_i + 1}$$
Each factor of the LHS is less than $1 + 1/(p_i - 1)$, which is $\le 3/2$ except for the case where $p_i = 2$. Hence LHS $< 3^{r-1}/2^{r-2}$ where $r$ is the number of factors, whereas RHS $\ge 2^{r - 1}$. The only values of $r$ for which $2^{r - 1} < 3^{r-1}/2^{r-2}$ are 1 and 2.

In the case of $r = 1$, we have LHS $< 2$ and RHS $\ge 1$, so that $k_1$ is 1 or 2. In either case, it is easy to check there is no corresponding $p_1$.

In the case of $r = 2$, we have LHS $< 3$ and RHS $\ge 2$, so that RHS is either 2 or $5/2$. Only in the case of RHS $= 2$, we find values for the $k_i$, namely $k_1 = k_2 = 1$. Equaling LHS to 2 we get an equation equivalent to $(p_1 - 1)(p_2 - 1) = 2$, which shows $n = 6$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really have to learn better to manipulate formulae especially with geometric series and products and such :)